# Get previous first value from parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a parameter date from dataset date:
Sample of data

| Key | Month | Year | Row num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210131 | January | 2021 | 3 |
| 20201231 | December | 2020 | 2 |
| 20201130 | November | 2020 | 1 |

I need to do an expression that returns the previous of selected value for example when a user selects January 2021(date parameter) it will return December 2020 in expression in text box.

I try `previous(first(fields! Month_year. Value, "group name"))` but it returns error, is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'selects'? is this data being used to populate parameter values? Edit you question to add more details, tell use where the selection takes place and where the result will be used (e.g. result will be used to pass to a query) or it will be displayed in a text box or in a table etc.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you extend the dataset query to include the previous value against each row.

Assuming you dataset query is called `DataSet1` and uses a table called 'myTable' then something like this (I changed the sample column name from Key to KeyID to avoid keyword problems).

```
    SELECT *
        , LAG(KeyID) OVER(ORDER BY RowNum) as PreviousMonthKeyID
        FROM myTable
```

NOTE: This assumes row number is always in the correct order, if not then you could change this to order by KeyID.

You can then use a `LOOKUP()` to find the correct value, so if your parameter is called `selectedDate` and it's value is set to the KeyID column, use something like

```
=LOOKUP(Parameters!selectDate.Value, Fields!KeyID.Value, Fields!PreviousMonthKey.Value, "DataSet1")
```

This reads "get the value in selectdDate, find this value in the column KeyID in the dataset called DataSet1 and return the value found in the column called PreviousMonthKeyID"